# Profiling a production node.js server in ECS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, profiling

I have a problem in my node.js server that suddenly the CPU spikes and the requests  have about 3-5 seconds latency.

This occurs once every few days and the only way to fix it is just `docker restart` I want to be able to pinpoint the problem (maybe an infinite while?).

So how do I profile a production node.js server in AWS? I understand I may need to add a line in my code to activate the profiler, redeployment for the profiler to work is ok.

Comment: Did you find the issue? iam having similar issue in m ECS nodejs container. what you found may help me. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a performace issue some time ago and I found a very convenient solution to track the issue down without much knowledge about profiling etc.

I used N|Solid by Nodesource [1]. Let me explain why it is so convenient:

1. Full node.js compatibility [2] - just replace node executable with nsolid executable.
2. Nice pricing [3] - free plan includes 5 monitored processes.
3. Beautiful visualizations - help you spot the issue quickly. [4]
4. Good documentation.
5. Fast setup - just create a free account, obtain a license key and set your docker containers up as described in the following docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.6"
services:
  nsolid_console:
    image: nodesource/nsolid-console
    ports:
      - 9001:9001
      - 9002:9002
      - 9003:9003
      - 6753:6753
    environment:
      - NSOLID_CONSOLE_LICENSE_KEY=${NSOLID_CONSOLE_LICENSE_KEY}
    volumes:
      - ./data/nsolid-console:/var/lib/nsolid/console
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - nsolid_console

  yourService:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - NSOLID_APPNAME=YourApp-Name
      - NSOLID_COMMAND=nsolid_console:9001
      - NSOLID_DATA=nsolid_console:9002 
      - NSOLID_BULK=nsolid_console:9003
    entrypoint: 
      - nsolid your-entrypoint.js
    depends_on:
      - nsolid_console
    links:
      - nsolid_console:nsolid_console
```

Please note: Replace `${NSOLID_CONSOLE_LICENSE_KEY}` with your obtained license key.

#### References

[1] https://nodesource.com/products/nsolid
[2] https://docs.nodesource.com/nsolid/3.4/docs#node-compatibility
[3] https://nodesource.com/products/pricing
[4] https://docs.nodesource.com/nsolid/3.4/docs#cpu-profiling